# Opencart convert 3,0 extension to 2,3

Tags: opencart-3

i want to convert payment extension from 3,0 version to 2,3,0,2 version. Converted twig files to tpl files using web convertor. put them to related folder, of course it did not work. This extension is like a credit card payment method.

i guess the folder paths are different between two versions. Can find comparing two versions.

What else i should think, web convertor is correct source?